# Three-finger swipe browser back

Tags: shortcuts, touchpad, windows-10

Windows 10 broke my three-finger swipe to browser back.  Now, it is the same action as the one-finger swipe-from-left-edge to switch programs provided in Windows 8/8.1.  Is there any way to get it back?

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I do not like how Windows 10 change this functionality. I use MS excel a lot and 3 fingers swipe left/right help flip between sheets. I also preferred the back/forth functionality.

anyway, I have found a weird workaround that I have to have MsExcel running and the 3 fingers swipe left/right will work like it was again (back/forth). I am sure this is a bug in Windows10 integration with Excel. It seems to have overwritten 3fingers swipe functionality.

enjoy